# interactive dynamic pattern with fabric js ( change pattern properties (height,left,top ....) using mouse events )

Tags: fabricjs

I want to make this dynamic pattern in fabric js interactive with the user for example if he presses Ctrl and selects the object with the mouse  I want the pattern properties to change, so I can move and scale the image inside pattern.
http://fabricjs.com/dynamic-patterns
any ideas thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it (hold down Ctrl key and select the object with the mouse):

```js
(function() {
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

  var polygon;
  var padding = 0;
  fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg', function(img) {

    img.scaleToWidth(100);
    
    var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
    patternSourceCanvas.add(img);

    var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
      source: function() {
        patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
          width: img.getWidth() + padding,
          height: img.getHeight() + padding
        });
        return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
      },
      repeat: 'repeat'
    });

    polygon = new fabric.Polygon([
      {x: 185, y: 0},
      {x: 250, y: 100},
      {x: 385, y: 170},
      {x: 0, y: 245} ], {
        left: 0,
        top: 70,
        angle: -15,
        fill: pattern,
        objectCaching: false
    });
    canvas.add(polygon);

    controlKeyDown = false;
    document.getElementById('c').focus();
    //setInterval only used in case you go "Full page" in the code snippet demo tool
    setInterval(function() {
      document.getElementById('c').focus();
    }, 1500);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      var keyCode = ('which' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
      controlKeyDown = (keyCode == 17);
    });
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(evn) {
      controlKeyDown = false;
    });
    
    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(evn) {
      mouseX = evn.e.offsetX;
      mouseY = evn.e.offsetY;
    });

    canvas.on('object:selected', function(e) {
      if (controlKeyDown) {
        var obj = e.target;
        //pattern position change
        polygon.points[0].x += mouseX;
        polygon.points[0].y += mouseY;
        polygon.points[1].x += 80;
        polygon.points[1].y -= 80;
        polygon.points[2].x += 60;
        polygon.points[2].y += 60;
        polygon.points[3].x += 80;
        polygon.points[3].y -= 80;
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
canvas {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas tabindex="1" id="c" width="440" height="440"></canvas>
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: thank's for your time but I want to change the pattern properties, not the selected object?

Comment: You want me to working on changing it so that when Ctrl key is down and you select the object the pattern properties change, right?  Could you update the question as such - so that others know?  Let me know!

Comment: I updated my answer...  Hope this is closer to what you want.

Comment: yeep !! not exactly I want the pattern position to change with mouse movement. thank you for you time

Comment: Updated to use mouse position.

Comment: you helped me to get the idea thanks, but not enough this is a what I want exactly thanks  https://jsfiddle.net/yjose/d1pq0ceL/3/

Comment: @ELAZIZIYoussouf, how can i modify pattern on already existing objects? canvas.getObjects()[0].get('fill').set({offsetX:200}); - that doesn't works...

Comment: Hi, take a  look at this new snippet https://jsfiddle.net/yjose/m5qdj8st/2/ . I use canvas.getObjects()[0].fill.offsetX  and it's work fine, i think you are using another version of fabricjs